# LINQPad 6 - change Temp directory with another one

Tags: linqpad

Is there a way to let LINQPad 6 use another directory instead of the user's temp?

I've checked LINQPad 6 preferences and there is no option where you can change the output directory. So, I was wondering if it is possible to do so in another way.

I need this because the company's antivirus always blocks each executes attempt from `AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad6\_XXX\YYY\name.dll` and I can't change those rules

Comment: Are you sure there's not a dll in there that *needs* to be blocked? If not, I think you better have the virus scanner's rules alleviated, because surely, not only Linqpad will be affected.

Comment: The antivirus is blocking each `LINQPadQuery.dll` and maybe I can avoid it. But there are some other dll which name is autogenerated like `TypedDataContext_vjwhwc.dll` and  `TypedDataContext_zbwhdx.dll`

Comment: I've the same problem with my antivirus, because LinqPadQuery.dll is always regenerated from query execution